# Call user defined function for entire column using the range method

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the following function on entire column. Can it be used using the range method? That way it would be fast rather than for loop, I guess.

```
Function cleanString(text As String) As String
Dim output As String
Dim c 'since char type does not exist in vba, we have to use variant type.
For i = 1 To Len(text)
    c = Mid(text, i, 1) 'Select the character at the i position
    If (c >= "a" And c <= "z") Or (c >= "0" And c <= "9") Or (c >= "A" And c <= "Z") Then
        output = output & c 'add the character to your output.
    Else
        output = output & " " 'add the replacement character (space) to your output
    End If
Next
cleanString = output 
End Function
```

Private Sub cmdGetItem_Click()

```
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlshdb As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng, rngdb As Range
Dim totalRows As Long
Dim r As Integer
Dim var As Variant

Set xlwb = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
Set xlsh = xlwb.Worksheets("Main")
Set xlshdb = xlwb.Worksheets("DB")
Set rng = xlsh.Range("C2:C" & LRow)
Set rngdb = xlshdb.Range("C:C").CurrentRegion
totalRows = rngdb.Rows.Count
Set rngdb = xlshdb.Range("C1:C" & totalRows)

xlsh.Range("M2:M" & LRow).Formula = "=cleanString(C2)"
xlsh.Range("C2:C" & LRow).Formula = xlsh.Range("M1:M" & LRow).Value

xlshdb.Range("M1:M" & totalRows).Formula = "=cleanString(C1)"
xlshdb.Range("C1:C" & totalRows).Formula = xlshdb.Range("M1:M" & LRow).Value
xlshdb.Range("D:D").Copy xlshdb.Range("N:N")
    
Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = xlsh.Range("M2:M" & LRow)

xlsh.Range("B2:B" & LRow) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng.Value, xlshdb.Range("M:N"), 2, False)

UserForm1.lstInvoiceItems.Refresh

xlwb.Close True

Set xlwb = Nothing: Set xlsh = Nothing: Set xlshdb = Nothing: Set rng = Nothing: Set rngdb = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use a search and replace or something with the dictionary but for a quick solution I would use a helper column and use Excels native incrementing ability against your UDF.

This will use your existing function as an Excel function into a helper column so it will increment, then it will copy across to the original location and finally delete the data in the helper column:

```
Sub Main()
Dim lr As Long
    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B1:B" & lr).Formula = "=cleanString(A1)"
    Range("A1:A" & lr).Formula = Range("B1:B" & lr).Value
    Range("B1:B" & lr).ClearContents
End Sub
```

A couple of caveats however:

Make sure you change all references to column B to a column with no data in which you don't care about.

Change all references to "A" to the column you want to clean including the start where it sets lr (last row)

Comment: Thank you! not sure why but am getting the #NAME? error in the excel sheet

Comment: That means it can't resolve. Is the function in a module on the same workbook? Update your post to include your new sub routine also so I can see if you missed a reference change.

Comment: no sir, its used on other worksheet, since i am using vlookup have not deleted the helper column. have added the sub which is using the function.

Comment: I don't think it works in a seperate workbook (I might be wrong here), either put the module in the workbook in question or create an Excel Add-in with the module in it. The Add-in is my preferred method, we have one here that has about 40 new formulas in it, we simply add it in to everyones excel and they get all the new toys I build availbe in every sheet.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and inputs. Will try with add-in (have never done that) :) and keep you posted.